# Angular $resource method PUT gets 404 not found on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest, angular-resource

I am creating my custom PUT method using Angular $resource.
But when i try to hit an equal REST url in NodeJs, its says that adreess which i sent is not found.

Here is my factory:

```
(function (angular) 
{
angular.module('projekat.resource',['ngResource'])
.factory('ProjekatEntry', ["$resource", function($resource)
{
    var ProjEntry = $resource('/api/projekat/:_id',
    {_id:'@_id'},
    {
        obrisiKorisnika: 
        {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'api/projekat/:_id/:korId'
        }

    });
    return ProjEntry;

}]);
}(angular));
```

Here is my angular code:

```
$scope.obrisiUsera = function (korisnik, index) 
    {   
            $scope.projUser.$obrisiKorisnika( {'korId': korisnik._id});
            $scope.projUser.korisnici.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.korEntries.push(korisnik);
    }
```

And here is my router:

```
.put('/:id/:korId', function(req, res, next) {
 console.log("dasdasasdasds");
 Korisnik.findOne({
"_id": req.params.korId
}, function(err, korisnik) {
if (err)
{
  console.log(err);
  next(err);
}
Korisnik.findByIdAndUpdate(korisnik._id, {$pull:{"projekti":req.params.id}}, function (err)
{
  if(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  }
});
Projekat.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$pull:{"korisnici":korisnik._id}}, function (err, entry) {
  if (err)
  {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  }
  res.json(entry);
   });
  });
})
```

But i think server side isnt the problem, because it never gets to the server, thats why error says :

> PUT http://localhost:8080/slickTask/api/projekat/5744b8802d28307020d8cc40/5744ba262d28307020d8cc4c 404 (Not Found)

My routers are fine, everything worked util now, POST, PUT, GET etc. but when i tried to use PUT method with another param, it doesn't hit my url on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Eventualy i found what was the problem.
URL of the PUT in the method of factory *ProjekatEntry* needs to be

> url: '/api/projekat/:_id/:korId'

with slash on the beginning of the url.
Thats why server side was never hit.